# Translating an Extension

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1, localisation

Are there any tools for generating a csv file for translations of a module? I.e. detecting calls to `__()` within a module and outputting the information into a csv ready to be used as a translation file for the module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a simple<sup>*</sup> GREP of your template files:

```
> grep "__\(.*?\)" -Roh . | sed "s/__([\"']//" | sed "s/[\"'].*//g" | sort | uniq
```

This will output a list of unique phrases - such as (ran against `/app/design/frontend/base/default/templates/)`:

```
You have not tagged any products yet.
You have placed no orders yet.
You have placed no orders.
You have placed no products yet.
```

This will get you 80% of the way there but now you'll need to do the following:

- This will return results for translations that are unquoted or are a direct translation of a variable, E.g. `$this->__($title)` - these will need to be removed and handled manually.
- You will need to copy this content into a second column, comma delimitted. I've gone to the trouble of adding the `sed` command onto the grep above so that it outputs all in one go:

  ```
  > grep "__\(.*?\)" -Roh . | sed "s/__([\"']//" | sed "s/[\"'].*//g" | sort | uniq | sed "s/\(.*\)/\"\1\",\"\1\"/"
  ```

---

<sub>* LOL this isn't terribly simple I guess</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the Grep, was trying to format something like that :)

Comment: Thanks. See the update which makes the output into a CSV with two columns.

Comment: Awesome, deserves a +1 :)

Comment: In the absence of any formalised tools this was going to be my approach. I guess I could also create an xml parser to extract the translatable elements from the config files. I'm just surprised nobody seems to have created a toolset for this yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some regular expressions that might help.
This should match `Mage::helper('some_helper')->__('Some text')`

```
'/helper\(\\\'([a-z_]+)\\\'\)-\>__\([\s]*([\'|\\\"])(.*?[^\\\\])\\2.*?\)/'
```

This should match `$this->__('Some Text')`

```
'/\$this-\>__\([\s]*([\'|\\\"])(.*?[^\\\\])\\1.*?\)/'
```

And for the XML files, just load the file as an xml object and then xpath the elements with the attribute `translate`.
**[Edit]**
I've recently put together an extension that should identify the translatable texts in a module and generate the csv file for it. [Check it out.](https://github.com/tzyganu/MagentoTranslationTool)

Answer (score 0):

No answer but a suggestion if that's ok.

Trying to make good translations without seeing the context around that phrase or word will be extremely hard.

I suggest trying to find a basic translation set and then go from there.
You can use the 'Inline translations' from the backend to see what parts in the webshop are translatable

Comment: I'm just creating a base translation file (i.e. en_US) rather than actually create a translation to another language. So the context doesn't really matter for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I used notepad++, opened all files and subfolders of the plugin in it.

Pressed CTRL + F and searched for __( and pressed search in all documents and then went over them all and copied them into an csv.

However you put it, it's going to be a lot of work ;-)