# How To Forward Port an Existing Language Pack

Tags: ee-1.13, language

For some languages (`en_UK`, `fi_FI` and others) there are outdated language packs available on Magento connect (in these cases based on Magento 1.6).

We are using a recent Enterprise Edition (1.13).

Basically we want to generate a new CSV files which contains all the texts of our current Magento version (i.e. from the `en_US` folder of Magento Core) and pre-fill / merge the already existing translations (from the outdated non-US-English language pack), so that a translator can fill the missing fields.

Are there tools for that / did anybody do this before?

*Remark: I did some edits for clarification in the text, so old comments might not apply anymore.*

Comment: I have the same problem with `pl_PL`. It would be a nice idea for a hackathon, in case there is no solution out there.

Comment: We built something which might help: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Hackathon_LocaleFallback

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt: I saw this project a while ago, but did not understand it because of poor README.md :-P

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt: Is the idea to use editor tools which are made for .po files for Magento?

Comment: The idea is, that you can have a fallback language. The usecase was: you have de_DE and de_CH, nearly everything is the same but a few are not, so if you don't find a phrase in de_CH look it up in the fallback, de_DE...

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt: okay, then I think this is not so much helpful concerning this specific topic (while still very interesting!)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution. It's more of an idea. You can identify the texts that are 'translatable' with a regex. [See the answers here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/translating-an-extension), then just parse the existing CSV files  (that should be easy) and merge the results.
If you use this regex `'/helper\(\\\'([a-z_]+)\\\'\)-\>__\([\s]*([\'|\\\"])(.*?[^\\\\])\\2.*?\)/'` it should identify the module names in texts like `Mage::helper('some_helper')->__('Some text')`.
The hard part in identifying the module is for texts like `$this->__('Some text')` but you should be able to get the module from the file path. Use this regex for that `'/\$this-\>__\([\s]*([\'|\\\"])(.*?[^\\\\])\\1.*?\)/'`.
For xml files it should be easy. Just parse them and look for the `translate` attribute.

Comment: In addition...some time ago there was a tool for identifying translatable texts that you could download from the EE account. It used the exact same regular expressions, but it's gone now. WHY MAGENTO TEAM...WHY?

Comment: Updated my question...

Comment: @Alex Ok. My answer still sounds valid to me. Unless I'm missing something. If so, please ignore me. tell me and I will delete the answer to avoid "background noise"

Comment: :) Will think about it more. But to find the texts from the code base, I think there is even some Magento tool...